# Generating a deep copy of NSDictionary in order to modify nested values

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

Imagine the scenario where you have an `NSDictionary` (not a `Dictionary`) that contains keys and values of different types, for example an `NSNumber` and another `NSDictionary`. And there may be several nested `NSDictionary`s. You now need to peek into every dictionary in this structure (no matter how far nested it is) looking for a specific key, and everywhere it is found, replace its value with a different value.

How can this be achieved in Swift - specifically Swift 2?

I'm thinking a deep mutable copy of this structure could be created (`NSMutableDictionary`), then possibly use recursion in order to process and modify each dictionary if necessary. Once completed, replace the original structure with the modified mutable structure. If that's a good approach, how can one perform a deep mutable copy of this structure in order to work with it? Or how else could this be accomplished?

For example, this could be the dictionary:

```
{
    NUMFRIENDS = 3;
    GREETING = 
    {
        HELLO = WORLD;
        WHATSUP = DUDE;
        ...
    }
    HELLO = WORLD;
    ...
}
```

And you wish to find all `HELLO` keys and replace their value with `UNIVERSE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C I've been using this trick:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self]]
```

That makes automatically a deep copy of all objects using NSCoding protocol.

So in Swift the same trick should work:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self))
```

Comment: Is that copy *mutable* (on all nested levels)?

Comment: If original object was mutable then yes :)

Comment: Wow this is beautiful. It is important to note you have to pass in an already mutable dictionary. Also note there's a typo in your Swift code - should be `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

Comment: Fixed NSKeyedUnarchiver, ,sorry was coding in textfield directly not from xcode. And yes you can always pass [mutableCopy]